# Как задать радиус или положение SVG через CSS-переменную

Tags: html, css, svg, css-variables

<sub>Перевод вопроса [@Gangula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6908282/gangula) на [EN SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69790363/6263942):</sub>

Можно ли с помощью CSS-переменных управлять в SVG такими значениями, как радиус или положение, **через атрибуты** элемента?

Вот, например, я задал переменные для цвета `--dark-text-clr` и радиуса `--radius`. Когда делаю [заливку цветом](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51395179/) — CSS-переменная работает (1ый круг), а когда использую переменную для радиуса — элемент не отображается (2ой круг).

```css
:root {
  --dark-text-clr: blue;
  --radius: 12;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
    <circle cx="9" cy="9" fill="var(--dark-text-clr)" mask="url(#moon-mask)" r=9 ></circle>
    <circle cx="36" cy="20" fill="var(--dark-text-clr)" mask="url(#moon-mask)" r="var(--radius)" ></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Перевод ответа [@Corrl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15388872/corrl) на [EN SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69790732/6263942):</sub>

Есть **три способа** задать значение для радиуса:

- через соответствующий атрибут

```html
<circle ... r=10>
```

- через классы и стили

```css
circle {
  r: 10px;
}
```

- через атрибут `style`

```html
<circle... style="r: 10px;" ></circle>
```

У последнего способа наивысший прироритет. Взгляните на этот пример. У всех трёх кругов есть `r` атрибут, но во 2ом круге его перебили свойства класса, а в 3ем круге всех одолел атрибут `style`.

(Нет нужды использовать все три способа вместе. Делаю это только, чтобы показать, как они переопределяют уже заданное значение.)

```css
:root {
  --dark-text-clr: purple;
  --radius: 20px;
}

.circle {
  r: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" fill="var(--dark-text-clr)" mask="url(#moon-mask)" r=5></circle>
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" fill="var(--dark-text-clr)" mask="url(#moon-mask)" r=5 class="circle"></circle>
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" fill="var(--dark-text-clr)" mask="url(#moon-mask)" r=5 class="circle" style="r: var(--radius);" ></circle>
</svg>
```

Похоже, атрибут `r` с CSS-переменной работает в Firefox, но **не в Chrome/Edge**:

```html
<circle ... r="var(--radius);" ></circle>
```

Так что **лучше воспользуйтесь** атрибутом `style`:

```html
<circle ... style="r: var(--radius);" ></circle>
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Перевод ответа [@Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) на [EN SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69790400/6263942) и комментариев к нему:</sub>

Да, но в CSS [нужно указывать единицы](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#length-value) для ненулевых значений.

Код ниже работает в Firefox и не работает в Edge или Chrome ([баг-репорт](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1265430)).

```css
:root{
  --dark-text-clr: blue;
  --radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
    <circle cx="9" cy="9" fill="var(--dark-text-clr)" mask="url(#moon-mask)" r=9 ></circle>
    <circle cx="36" cy="20" fill="var(--dark-text-clr)" mask="url(#moon-mask)" r="var(--radius)" ></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Здесь странный ответ для одного браузера. На enSO тоже его не отметил.

Comment: @Leonid Согласен. Оставил его ради внятного замечания, что CSS переменной нужны единицы измерения, хотя атрибут, в который она встаёт, работает без них.

Comment: Я попробовал удалить px из ответа Corrl, удалил и width-height атрибуты svg. Все прекрасно работает. И масштабируется тоже. Кстати с px тоже масштабировалось - получается, что единицы как раз игнорируются, а передаются относительные значения. https://jsfiddle.net/7ce3ms8a/

Comment: @Leonid Проверил в файерфоксе для `<circle cx="60" cy="60" fill="var(--dark-text-clr)" mask="url(#moon-mask)" r="var(--radius)" ></circle>`. Если переменная стоит в атрибуте `r`, то при значении `20px` круг отображается, а при просто `20` пропадает. А в хроме не видно круга что так, что эдак. https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/ktx8rapc/

Comment: Да, я тоже посмотрел, что в Firefox не работает. Значит, в этом и принципиальная разница. При этом, если указать `px`, то все равно масштабируется и в Firefox.  Не принимает без единиц, но и преобразовывает в уловные единицы SVG.